# Why is my java calculator code not working?

Tags: java, calculator

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author zhoushi15
 */
public class Calculator {
    public static double num1;
    public static double num2;
    public static String opp;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static double sum;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        boolean quit;
        String calculator;
        String exp;
        System.out.print("Welcome to the AP Computer Science calculator!!");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean calc = false;
        while (calc == false) {
            System.out.print("Enter an expression, or quit to exit: ");
            exp = input.nextLine();
            if (exp.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for stopping by!");
                calc = true;
            } else {
                token(exp);
                System.out.println(exp + "=" + sum);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void token(String x) {
        Scanner jz = new Scanner(x);
        if (jz.hasNextDouble()) {
            if (jz.hasNextDouble()) {
                num1 = jz.nextDouble();
            } else {
                System.out.println("error! It is not a number.");
            }
            if (jz.hasNext()) {
                opp = jz.next();
            }
            if (jz.hasNextDouble()) {
                num2 = jz.nextDouble();
            }
        } else if (jz.hasNext()) {
            if (jz.hasNext()) {
                opp = jz.next();
            }
            if (jz.hasNextDouble()) {
                num1 = jz.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void opp(double num1, String opp, double num2) {
        if (opp.equals("+")) {
            sum = num1 + num2;
        } else if (opp.equals("-")) {
            sum = num1 - num2;
        } else if (opp.equals("*")) {
            sum = num1 + num2;
        } else if (opp.equals("/")) {
            sum = num1 / num2;
        }
    }

    public static void opp2(String opp, double num1) {
        if (opp.equals("|")) {
            sum = Math.abs(num1);
        } else if (opp.equals("v")) {
            sum = Math.sqrt(num1);
        } else if (opp.equals("~")) {
            sum = Math.round(num1);
        } else if (opp.equals("s")) {
            sum = Math.sin(num1);
        } else if (opp.equals("c")) {
            sum = Math.cos(num1);
        } else if (opp.equals("t")) {
            sum = Math.tan(num1);
        }
    }
}
```

my code
is not
giving the answer.for example,my input is 4+5,then the output is0.0,but i can't find where's the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Please, *please* fix the indentation.

Comment: Run your code with debugger.

Comment: What's with testing hasNextDouble() twice in a row?

Comment: How does this compile? You have a name collision between a function and a variable.

Comment: DO NOT use the same name for methods and variables, you're just going to confuse the hell out of yourself. Rename either public static String opp; to something else, or public static void opp to something else. Do not simply make it opp1.

Method and variable names exist to help you. They would make sense out of this program. Do not simply name things at random.

Comment: I'd like to offer you as tip as well OP. Things like `while (calc == false)` are better represented as `while (!calc)` and vice versa for true/false evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

Taking a look at your `main` method, you never assign a value to the variable `sum` or call a method that would do so. Therefore, your calculator always prints the result as `0.0` which is the default initialized value for doubles. `opp` and `opp2` are not used automatically, you need to actually call them.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has several design issues. Currently the main will call into token(), which sets opp, num1, and num2. Then it returns to main and then main prints 0.

You need to actually do something with num1 and num2. Either have token() call opp1() or opp2() based on the value of opp, or have main call opp1() or opp2() after token().

```
else {
     token(exp);
     System.out.println(exp + "=" + sum);
}
```

instead

```
else{
    token(exp);
    if(opp == "+"){
           sum = opp(num1, opp, num2);
    }
    else{
           sum = opp2(num1, num2);
    }
    System.out.println(exp + "=" + sum);
}
```

Also for the love of god please rename all your variables and method names. Everything will make more sense to you that way.

Answer (score 2):

As many ppl pointed out - just try to run your program with debugger, then you can see where at least the problems start :)

What ppl have said about sum not being assigned (only initialized) is true and that is a reason why you are getting 0.0 as a result at everything you input.

If you would run with debugger you would notice that `jz.hasNextDouble()` always return false and subsequently `jz.hasNext()` returns true and that results in `op` be the whole expression that you have entered, and at that point you are leaving `token`method and printing your `sum`

Answer (score 1):

You are never assigning `sum` ghd `opp` and `opp2` methods are not being invoked, that's why